# Mocking a collection and logic inside a loop

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am stuck with a test case written in mockito+junit 
Here to find help for the same . the secenario is as follows

```
Class Application{
//property 1 
//property 2
ForeignCollection<Key> keys; //Key class contains multiple keys for same application id and this field does not exist in application Table 
}
```

This is the method for which i want to create my test case

```
  class ClassService{
    public Response method(Request request){
    //some lines of code
    verifyKey(request,Application app); //a private method of same class
    }

   private void verifyKey(Request r,Application a){
        boolean matched = false;
        Iterable<Key> keys = application.getSecretKeys().getWrappedIterable();
        for(Key key : keys )
        if(request.headers("Key").equals(key.getKey())) secretKeyMatched=true;
        if(!secretKeyMatched)  throw new InvalidSecretKeyException(request.headers("Secret-Key"),"INVALID SECRET KEY");
     }
   }
```

And below is the test case

```
 Class TestClass{
       @Mock
       private ForeignCollection<Key> keyForeignCollection;
       @Mock
       Request request;
       @Mock
       Response response;
       @Mock
       ClassService classService;
       //below are not mocked
       private CloseableWrappedIterable<Key> closeableWrappedIterableOfKey;
       private Iterable<Key> IterableOfKey;
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
      keyForeignCollection.add(Key object);
      keyFoerignCollection.add(Key object);
      }
    public void shouldMethod(){
    keyForeignCollection.add(make(a(keyMaker.ApplicationSecretKey)));
    application.setkeys(keyForeignCollection);
   when(applicationSecretKeyForeignCollection.size()).thenReturn(2);
   when(application.getKeys().getWrappedIterable()).thenReturn(closeableWrappedIterableOfKey);
  when(request.headers("Key")).thenReturn("some-key"); when(application.getKeys().getWrappedIterable()).thenReturn(keyForeignCollection.getWrappedIterable());
//
Response response = clasService.method(request);
Map<String, String> responseBody = (Map<String, String>) response.getBody();

    }
}
```

whenever the method gets called from the test case it throws null pointer exception due to call of internal method ie verify(Request,Application);

Help !

Comment: Don't mock collections: use a real collection, containing mock values, if necessary.

Comment: Your code input would not even compile! You want us to spend **our** time to help you solving **your** problem. So **you** please spend the 5 minutes it takes to A) properly format/indent all of your code B) make sure that you are really posting the code that you have in place.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your goal is to bypass the call to the verifyKey method, not to test it; you can [use a Spy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_spying.htm). Annotate classService with `@Spy` and mock the ClassService::verifyKey(Request, Application) method.

To mock a void method just write

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(classService ).verifyKey(x, y);
```

[Official doc about spies](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T)).